# How to redirect http to https for sites behind proxy?

Tags: apache, ssl, proxy

This is the situation. We have a server hosting sites that is behind the apache proxy server. We have purchased recently SSL certification and the configuration has been made to both virtual host80 and 443. The problem is with proxy server. Can you guys please advise how to configure proxy server in order to redirect http to https? Thanks in advance,